# constraint layout has extra space at bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am implementing a view which uses constraint layout inside of scroll view. I am trying to align a view to the bottom of parent using `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent` However there is extra white space below my view as you can see in the picture. The white space below blue color view. Can someone guide me on how to remove the extra white space at the bottom. Thanks in advance.

[image]

here is the code

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="90dp"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="275dp"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/bubble_exclaimation"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/content_layout"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/title"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/body"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right_guideline"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/body"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                    android:text="@string/content_small"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right_guideline"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" />

                <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                    android:id="@+id/left_guideline"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.11" />

                <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                    android:id="@+id/right_guideline"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.89" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


    </ScrollView>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/block"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/scrollView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image"` from `android:id="@+id/content_layout"`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fadingEdge="vertical"
            android:fadingEdgeLength="90dp"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minHeight="275dp"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/bubble_exclaimation"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/content_layout"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/content_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/title"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/title"
                        android:textSize="17sp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/body"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right_guideline"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/body"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                        android:text="@string/content_small"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right_guideline"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" />

                    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                        android:id="@+id/left_guideline"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.11" />

                    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                        android:id="@+id/right_guideline"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.89" />
                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


        </ScrollView>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/block"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/scrollView" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Why this happens when we write `layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent` or `layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent`? @MJM

Comment: using this both property it,align content to center same like relative layout ,align_botton and align_top is view is wrap_content it align in center of screen